# How to get jQuery dialog buttons to extend beyond the dialog box and displayed next to each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, dialog

Making a dialog box with options to choose from, but when the text in the buttons is too long they stack beneath each other. I need it to stay next to each other (and maybe also extent beyond the width of the dialog box). Have tried different displays and floats but can't get anything to change...

I want it to look like this (I left out the CSS in this post so don't pay attention to that):

[image of how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVbli.png)

Also: **HAVE to use jQuery as it's for a school project...**

The HTML:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="click-button4">Attack</button>

<div id="dialog4">
    <p>Which attack do you want to use?</p>
</div>
</body>
```

And the JavaScript / jQuery:

```
$("#click-button4").click(function () {
        $("#dialog4").css("display", "block");

        $(function() {
            $("#dialog4").dialog({
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: "Use sword",
                        click: function() {
                            console.log("Use sword");
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Slap him",
                        click: function() {
                            console.log("Slap him");
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Scream at him",
                        click: function() {
                            console.log("Scream at him");
                        }
                    },
                ]
            }).dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-title").hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you add the `script` and `link` tags for the `dialog` import in your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this? I added a `white-space: nowrap` css property to the button text.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ln9rbs4c/1/

Comment: I added an image of how I'd like it to look now for clarification. I tried your solution but didn't do that for me sadly so I hope I'm more clear now

Comment: Ah ok, I will see what I can do

Comment: Wait sorry, it did work, I just had to put the code somewhere else! Still a programming noobie. Thanks so much!

Comment: Oh great no problem